# Microphone NOT working on Ubuntu 16.04.02TLS GNOME

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Today I decided I will install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 10 in a dual-boot system. After installing everything, I decided to install Discord to talk with some friends, and I noticed that my mic wasn't working. I thought that there may be a problem with my Discord install, but there isn't after I checked that my mic wasn't working in many more programs (including System Settings → Sound where no sound was showing up).

I also have to mention that my sound is working completely fine. It's just the mic that's not working. Microphone is part of my headset (CREATIVE Sound BlasterX H7).

I checked all the forums and tried many different solutions. Some of them were:

- checking that the microphone isn't muted (it isn't);
- checking my settings in the pavucontrol panel. Trying to split the channels and lowering each channel at a time to check if the mic will work after that;
- looking at the Configuration panel in pavucontrol and setting it to Analog Stereo Duplex
- looking at the alsamixer and checking that the mic isn't muted
  (look at the picture below) [I may have overlooked this step]
- trying to install a new vivid alsa dkms driver
- restarting the audio drivers

I am 100% sure my microphone is functioning, since I can use it without any problems on Windows 10 or on any other machine.

---

Important specs [since the problem may be linked to my hardware]:

- i7-6700k Skylake
- z170x gaming 7 Gigabyte
- two monitors, each having its own speakers

---

Alsamixer Volume Control image:

[image]

---

The audio devices:

```
➜  ~ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I don't see a possible reason so far (though you shouldn't use 153% input level, but that's unrelated). Please plug in your headset, put the output of `aplayer -c0 mixer` and `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec\#*` into a pastebin or similar and edit your question with a link.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is with the CA0132 sound card and its inability to communicate with Linux machines. There is no driver for that sound card and there are a dozen more persons having this problem since ~2013. Sorry to disappoint. I answered just to make you not lose your time with this endless problem. Let's hope Creative are going to release a Linux driver for the sound card in the near future.